# Excel Divide By Zero Error - Mass Update

Tags: excel-formula, divide-by-zero

I have an existing workbook that I am updating, and it has a lot of #DIV/0! errors.  Is there a quick way that I can correct all of them (or at least a lot at once)?  Adding an =If statement to every individual cell would take forever!

More info:

All of the #DIV/0! errors come from cells where I have a formula that is dividing the values of two different cells i.e. =cll/c12.  In a lot of these cases, the denominator is zero, so it gives the error.  I am looking for a fast way to correct several thousand of these errors without having to manually add error checking to each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the little information I gathered from the question

You can perform a `Find and Replace`

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the Find and Replace screen

[image]

## Updated:

Step 1: `Select the range` that you will work with.

Step 2: Press the `F5 key` to open the Go To dialog box.

Step 3: Click the `Special button`, and it opens the `Go to Special` dialog box.

Step 4: In the Go to Special dialog box, only check the `Errors option`

Step 5: And then click OK, `all # formula` errors have been selected

Step 6: Now just enter 0 or any other value that you need to replace the errors, and press **Ctrl + Enter** keys. Then you will get all selected error cells are filled with 0 or your formula

Of course, you can delete all of error cells with pressing the Delete key, leaving the blank cells.

[Screenshots and Src](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/828-excel-replace-0-blank.html)

Comment: Technically that would get the desired result, but I would lose all the formulas.  What  I believe I really need is a way to mass update all of these with error checking, so that "=C2/C1" becomes "=IFERROR(C2/C1, 0). I will see if I can replace "=" with "=IFERROR(" and append ", 0)" to the end of the cells.

Comment: Important thing is after Step 5 ,when all the error cells are selected, just type in the formula bar =IFERROR(C11/C12,0) then hit Ctrl+Enter

Comment: That's really close. The only problem now is, when I select rows and columns together and update them, it automatically changes the values. Each column uses the same cell for the denominator, and when I do this, it increments the denominator to the next cell.

Comment: Use the $ for the denominator =IFERROR(C11/$C$12,0) as required!

Comment: Well, that works as long as I only select one column at a time.  But if I select several rows and columns, it sets all the denominators the same.  Isn't there a way to set it as "=IFERROR(cell formula or content, 0)"?